# Is there any alternative for "limitTo" in Angular2 or plus

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

As in Angularjs (Angular-1) there is a **limitTo filter** to limit your text that you have to display

Ex: If I have a string like

```
$scope.val = "hey there how are you";
```

and I have to display only limited text on HTML side so I used

```
{{val | limiteTo:10}}
```

So its display only 10 char from a string like :: **hey there**

I'm moved on Angualr2 and I don't know how can it be done here, I used the same filter but it won't work

Comment: Slice pipe is way to go for it, check [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjhaa6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar its works

Answer (score 1):

Use SlicePipe

> Creates a new Array or String containing a subset (slice) of the
>   elements.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slice-string-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>{{str}}[0:4]: '{{str | slice:0:4}}' - output is expected to be 'abcd'</p>
    <p>{{str}}[4:0]: '{{str | slice:4:0}}' - output is expected to be ''</p>
    <p>{{str}}[-4]: '{{str | slice:-4}}' - output is expected to be 'ghij'</p>
    <p>{{str}}[-4:-2]: '{{str | slice:-4:-2}}' - output is expected to be 'gh'</p>
    <p>{{str}}[-100]: '{{str | slice:-100}}' - output is expected to be 'abcdefghij'</p>
    <p>{{str}}[100]: '{{str | slice:100}}' - output is expected to be ''</p>
  </div>`
})
export class SlicePipeStringComponent {
  str: string = 'abcdefghij';
}
```

Or Else Create Custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'slice'
})
export class SlicePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, start?: any, end?: any): any {
    if (start == null && end == null) {
      return value;
    }
    else {
      return value.slice(start, end);
    }
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uv5gvs

Ref:https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 0):

There is slice pipe in Angular 4, you can use that and also below is the code snippet from **tutorialspoint.com** and below i have attached a link also for the same.

```html
<div style="width:40%;float:left;border:solid 1px black;">
  <h1>Json Pipe</h1>
  <b>{{ jsonval | json }}</b>
  <h1>Percent Pipe</h1>
  <b>{{00.54565 | percent}}</b>
  <h1>Slice Pipe</h1>
  <b>{{months | slice:2:6}}</b> // here 2 and 6 refers to the start and the end index
</div>
```

[Angular 4 pipes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_pipes.htm)

[Built in pipes Angular](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/pipes/built-in-pipes/)